# Getting values from Get and Set methods using separate classes

Tags: java

I am new to `Java`:

I have the following program that connects to different databases using an `Enum` to call the different database connection.

I need to put the credentials, username and password in a class by itself but I am not sure because they are both initialized using get and set and the only way I can get this to work is called them both in the same method.

First I have this class which initializes the connection strings and data elements.

```
class DatabaseUtility {

    private String USERNAME;
    private String PASSWORD;
    private String HSQLDB;
    private String MYSQL;

    public DatabaseUtility() {
        USERNAME = null;
        PASSWORD = null;
        HSQLDB = null;
        MYSQL = null;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return USERNAME;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        USERNAME = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return PASSWORD;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        PASSWORD = password;
    }

    public String getHsdbConn() {
        return HSQLDB;
    }

    public void setHsdb(String hsdbConnection) {
        HSQLDB = hsdbConnection;
    }

    public String getMySqlConn() {
        return MYSQL;
    }

    public void setMySqlConn(String mySqlConnection) {
        MYSQL = mySqlConnection;
    }
}
```

Next I have an `enum` use to call both db types:

```
public enum DBType {

    HSQLDB, MYSQL
}
```

Next I have a method which uses a switch statement to assign the different db connection based on the user preference in the `main method`.

*This is the focus of my post, I have to call both the get and set methods in here, I would rather not set the credentials in the same method but not sure how to separate the two.

```
import java.sql.*;

class DatabaseConnectivity {

    DatabaseUtility dbUtil = new DatabaseUtility();

    public Connection getConnection(DBType dbType) throws SQLException {

        dbUtil.setHsdb("jdbc:hsqldb:data/explorecalifornia");
        dbUtil.setMySqlConn("jdbc:mysql://jsa/explorecalifornia");
        dbUtil.setUsername("dbuser");
        dbUtil.setPassword("dbpassword");

        switch (dbType) {
        case MYSQL:
            return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUtil.getMySqlConn(),
                    dbUtil.getUsername(), dbUtil.getPassword());
        case HSQLDB:
            return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUtil.getHsdbConn(),
                    dbUtil.getUsername(), dbUtil.getPassword());
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the main class, notice the DBType enum called in the `try catch block`.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MultiDatabaseConnectionMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        DatabaseConnectivity databaseConnectivity = new DatabaseConnectivity();

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultset = null;

        try {

            connection = databaseConnectivity.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);

            System.out.println("Connected");
            System.out.println();

            statement = connection.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM states");

            resultset.last();
            System.out.println("Number of rows: " + resultset.getRow());

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (resultset != null) {
                resultset.close();
            }

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: You may want to stick to normal Java naming conventions, e.g., member variables start with a lower-case letter. Also, stuff like properties probably want to live in a property file instead, since there are canned solutions for things like this, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: I know and understand that, those data members where originally Constants but I change the type because I cannot use constant is a set method and forgot to change the name format. Eclipse also provides a warning. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but I think what you are asking is that you have to call dbUtil.set* and dbUtil.get* in the same method.

What I would suggest is that you create enum with db properties so whatever dbType passed to the argument you can just call getters on them. You can define your enum as below.

```
public enum DBType {
    //ser properties you want for db. url, username are just dummy values
    HSQLDB("url", "username", "password"), MYSQL("url", "username", "password");
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private DBType(String url, String username, String password){
        this.url = url;
        //set other properties
    }
    public String getUrl(){
        return this.url;
    }
    //getter for all the other values

}
```

and in DatabaseConnectivity's getConnection method will be

```
public Connection getConnection(DBType dbType) throws SQLException {

        return DriverManager.getConnection(dbType.getUrl(),
                    dbType.getUsername(), dbType.getPasword());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide credentials in the constructor of class `DatabaseConnectivity` and then use them to set values in the instance of `DatabaseUtility`.

```
class DatabaseConnectivity {
     DatabaseUtility dbUtil;
    public DatabaseConnectivity (String userName, String password)  {
       dbUtil = new DatabaseUtility();
        dbUtil.setUsername(userName)
        dbUtil.setPassword(password);
     }
    ......
```